# Better way of binding $ to jQuery

Tags: jquery, standards

To make sure that `$` is always referencing `jQuery`, I code in this format:

**Method #1**

`(function($) {
    // Use $ here
})(jQuery);`

As per my understanding, the function we created is called immediately and we are passing `jQuery` to it and catching it in `$` so our `$` will always reference to `jQuery`. Safest way, jQuery plugins are coded this way.

Now, I see some developers coding in the following format, which appears to work just fine but wanted to confirm if its correct & safe because I don't understand how it can work fine.

**Method #2**

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // Use $ here 
});​`

So, in this method, document ready function is called by directly using `jQuery` which is OK, but then $ is passed to it and now there is no means by which we can be sure it will reference to jQuery only, correct? Like Prototype was loaded after jQuery on page, then this `$` will reference to prototype instead of jQuery inside it.

So, in a nutshell, are both methods safe? If yes, how and which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are safe; jQuery [will pass itself as the argument](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a9c2a9bf61af4c09e8f089b45e8986b9a5416d46/src/core.js#L392) to the function passed to `ready`.

They are both appropriate for different things. The first one is more appropriate when you want the code to execute immediately rather than waiting for the document to be ready. The latter is more appropriate when you want to execute code when the document is ready.

Comment: Thanks! "jQuery will pass itself" Exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are safe. Use the latter if you want your code to execute as soon as the DOM is ready, and the first method if you want to run it immediately.

You might want to combine it though:

```
(function($) {
    // code that runs immediately

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // code that runs when the DOM is ready
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Thanks!